# Python- scarp text after comma

Tags: python

I have text file such as : abc,1,cde,2,fgh,3 and I want delete third string in my example it would be "cde" so finally result will be abc,1,2,fgh,3

I wrote code but I stuck how to delete , this is fragment of my code

```
for inline in infile:
        currentline = inline.split(",")
        print(currentline[2]
```

I try find answer on this forum , but I cant find them. I except links to similar example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. Once you split the line into parts using the comma as a delimiter, you can remove the third element from the list and then join the remaining elements back together with commas. Here's how you can do it:

```
for inline in infile:
    # Split the line into parts using comma as delimiter
    currentline = inline.strip().split(",")
    
    # Check if there are at least three parts
    if len(currentline) >= 3:
        # Remove the third element (index 2) from the list
        del currentline[2]
        
        # Join the remaining elements back together with commas
        modified_line = ','.join(currentline)
        
        # Print the modified line
        print(modified_line)
    else:
        # Print the original line if it doesn't have enough parts
        print(inline.strip())
```